# Phonegap Blackberry application build not generating StanderedInstall.zip and OTAInstall files

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks, phonegap-build

I am developing a phonegap App. I successfully developed this app for android now I am deploying this with Blackberry.
I follow the guideline as listed at phonegap site
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20BlackBerry

so I just copy the sample folder and try to deploy it with command line but i am not getting the OTAInstall and StanderedInstall files.

this is my cmd output :-

```
C:\Users\Dell\workspace\DSS>ant blackberry build
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\li
b\tools.jar
Buildfile: C:\Users\Dell\workspace\DSS\build.xml

blackberry:

build:

generate-cod-name:
     [echo] Generated name: cordovaExample.cod

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\Dell\workspace\DSS\build

package-app:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\Dell\workspace\DSS\build\widget
     [copy] Copying 22 files to C:\Users\Dell\workspace\DSS\build\widget
      [zip] Building zip: C:\Users\Dell\workspace\DSS\build\cordovaExample.zip

build:
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing command line options
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing bbwp.properties
     [exec] [INFO]                      Validating application archive
     [exec] [INFO]                      Parsing config.xml
     [exec] [INFO]                      Populating application source
     [exec] [INFO]                      Compiling BlackBerry WebWorks applicatio
n
     [exec] I/O Error: Cannot run program "C:\Program": CreateProcess error=2, T
he system cannot find the file specified
     [exec] [ERROR]                     RAPC exception occurred

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 27 seconds

C:\Users\Dell\workspace\DSS>
```

the modification I did in project.properties is as follows :-

```
blackberry.bbwp.dir=C:\\Program Files\\Research In Motion\\BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5
playbook.bbwp.dir=C:\\Program Files\\Research In Motion\\BlackBerry WebWorks SDK for TabletOS 2.1.0.6\\bbwp
qnx.bbwp.dir=C:\\Program Files\\Research In Motion\\BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.4.11


blackberry.mds.dir=C:\\Program Files\\Research In Motion\\BlackBerry Email and MDS Services Simulators 4.1.4\\MDS


blackberry.sigtool.password=prvnsharma


playbook.sigtool.csk.password=prvnsharma
playbook.sigtool.p12.password=prvnsharma


qnx.sigtool.password=prvnsharma


blackberry.sim.password=prvnsharma
```

please guys help me.

Comment: I solved the Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\li
b\tools.jar 
by setting JAVA_HOME var but still i ma not getting installation files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it myself by downgrading the JDK to 1.7 to JDK 1.6. I don't know whats happening. But above JDK 1.6.43 ant build have these errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, It's seem to be something about java being installed under "Program Files" the space between both words throws the error, I changed the java folder (and the ant configuration to that folder) and it worked just fine.